# Xcode: I've set my UIImageView to both Min and Max width, then why is it always the smallest size?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I've put the following constraints to my UIImageView (Name = RunwayGallery):

```
Width: >= 200
Width: <= 600
Align Center X to: Superview
100:133 Ratio to: RunwayGallery
Top Space to: ImageAbove, Equals 10
```

So why is the UIImageView always 200 width? Even when there is enough screen space on both sides (and below) to enlarge the UIImageView to fill the screen.

Many thanks.

Comment: Because your constraints are ambiguous.  Any width between 200 and 600 would satisfy them and autolayout happens to pick 200.

Comment: Seems fair. Then how should I add the constraints if I want a maximum width but it resizes when the screen becomes too small?

Comment: Perhaps: width = 600 with priority = 900 and width >= 200 with priority = 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Don't define the width of the image view in constraints. Define the padding that you want to the left and the right of the image view. Then auto layout can make your image view as large as possible without growing too large.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add more constraints to tell the UIImageView which width between 200 and 600 to choose.

What do you expect the width of the superview to be? Assuming the superview's width will be between 200 and 600, you can tell the UIImageView to fill the width of the superview by removing both width constraints and adding the following constraints:

```
Leading Space to: Superview Equals: 0
Trailing Space to: Superview Equals: 0
```

Now the UIImageView knows to stretch so that there is no space between its leading (left) and trailing (right) sides and the superview's leading and trailing sides.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I've mixed some of the answers of you guys and came up with this:

```
Leading Space to: Superview Equals: 0 (priority 900)
Trailing Space to: Superview Equals: 0 (priority 900)
width <= 600 (priority 1000)
```

This fully works. It makes sense if you think about it. It is filling to both sides with the leading and trailing space, UNLESS it becomes greater than 600.

Thanks for the answers! Appreciated.

EDIT: This is still the same:

```
Align Center X to: Superview
100:133 Ratio to: RunwayGallery
Top Space to: ImageAbove, Equals 10
```